# Angular Http params is not being sent

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am trying to make a get request using the following method:

```
    let ht = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
    'params': '{where:{id: 1}}'
});
return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + route, {headers: ht});
```

The request goes through but does not send the parameters can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you actually want to send a header named params, or did you mean those as query parameters (in which case see https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters)?

Comment: If by **params** you mean headers, then it's normal that they are not sent in an `OPTIONS` request. They'll show in the subsequent GET  request, if CORS settings allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the HttpParams from http to send the extra parameters to the api call.

```
import {HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

let ht = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
});

//Create new HttpParams
let p= new HttpParams().
         set("param1",p1).
         set("param2", p1); 

return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + route, {headers: ht, params: p});
```

Comment: Hello so this seems kinda tedious isnt there a better way i can write instead of:  .set('filter', '{"where": {"id": 1}}');

Comment: You should pass only a data in the params. what ever logic you need, you can implement that in the server where the api is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, think params go extra and are not part of the headers when sinding a request.

```
let ht = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
});

let p = {where:{id: 1}};

return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + route, {headers: ht, params: p});
```